# Importing a node module in TypeScript with type definitions

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

The answers I currently see on the web are seemingly out-of-date.

I have `node_modules/leaflet-draw` and `node_modules/@types/leaflet-draw` installed.

This line works:

`import * as L from 'leaflet';`

However this line does not:

`import * as foo from 'leaflet-draw';`

I receive this error:

`/node_modules/@types/leaflet-draw/index.d.ts' is not a module.`

To add confusion, this line works:

`var leafletDraw = require('leaflet-draw');`

Can anyone help me make sense of this?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source for [@types/leaflet-draw](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/1636a8e3aa8756a36d79700fbc71e8e30581fac7/leaflet-draw/index.d.ts) and [@types/leaflet](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/ae4fe7b6dec1fbbee9a2b454e7cc389b3bd2fd35/leaflet/index.d.ts), it appears that @types/leaflet is where the actual module declaration occurs:

```
declare module 'leaflet' {
    export = L;
}
```

while in @types/leaflet-draw, the namespace `L` is just extended (therefore adding all of its members to the original `leaflet` module).

Comment: What would be the proper import statement in this situation?

Comment: I would go with `import * as L from 'leaflet';` from a TypeScript perspective. Assuming leaflet and leaflet-draw are set up correctly, `L` should have all of the properties of leaflet-draw (as well as the ones of leaflet).